# (Where) does Plato define perfect number?

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, ancient-greece, number-theory

I've read several texts suggesting that Plato defines "perfect number" in his Republic, book VIII 546 b. However, there's no definition as we can see from - for example - this [translation](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/55201/55201-h/55201-h.htm#BookVIII): "... Now that which is of divine birth has a period which is contained in a perfect number$^1$ but the period of human birth..."

"1: i.e. a cyclical number, such as 6, which is equal to the sum of its divisors 1, 2, 3, so that when the circle or time represented by 6 is completed, the lesser times or rotations represented by 1, 2, 3 are also completed."

So it's just the footnotes that explain what the perfect number is. Where does Plato himself define it?

Comment: Did you read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plato%27s_number)? "The introductory words mention (a period comprehended by) 'a perfect number' which is taken to be a reference to Plato's perfect year mentioned in his Timaeus (39d)".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plato does not define perfect numbers anywhere. The earliest extant definition is in Euclid VII, def. 22. Although Plato uses the term "perfect number" I do not think it certain that he understood this phrase in the same way as Euclid.

Comment: Or, using perfect numbers for some numerological thing that has little to do with mathematics...